# ImportError: No module named log

Tags: python

Isn't log a built in package in python?

```
# /usr/bin/python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Oct 11 2015, 17:47:16) 
[GCC 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import log as logging
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named log
>>>
```

Do I need to install `log` with pip ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`logging` is a [built-in package](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html), not `log`:

```
import logging as log
```